# Проблемы с многопоточностью

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-threads

Есть код:

```
 if(immortalityOn){
        Log.d("immortalityOn", String.valueOf(immortalityOn));
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(7000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                immortalityOn = false;
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Переменной immortalityOn значение false должно присваиваться всегда спустя 7 секунд, после того, как ей было присвоено значение true. Но иногда этого ожидания не происходит и переменная сразу получает значение false

Доработанный вариант (который, правда, вообще вылетает, через несколько секунд после начала работы):

```
    if(immortalityOn){
        Log.d("immortalityOn", String.valueOf(immortalityOn));
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(7000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("immortalityOn", String.valueOf(immortalityOn));
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(7000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        immortalityOn = false;
                    }
                }, 7000);
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

---

Вернулся к первоначальному варианту и сделал так, чтобы переменная, находящаяся в if (заключил в if другую переменную, вместо immortalityOn), меняла значение по нажатию кнопки, результат: меняю переменную на false, она ждёт 7 секунд, меняет значение immortalityOn на false, но после, когда переменная immortalityOn получает значение true, оно сразу меняется на false, без ожидания 7 секунд:

```
if(!soundOn){
            Log.d("immortalityOn", String.valueOf(immortalityOn));
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(7000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    immortalityOn = false;
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

Comment: А у Вас immortalityOn в главном потоке находится?

Comment: @Crush, да_____

Comment: Вот ниже опередили с решением через Handler. =) Хотя оно "морозит" основной поток.

Comment: @Crush, вернулся к первоначальному варианту и сделал так, чтобы переменная, находящаяся в if, меняла значение по нажатию кнопки, результат: меняю переменную на false, она ждёт 7 секунд, меняет значение immortalityOn на false, но после, когда переменная immortalityOn получает значение true, оно сразу меняется на false, без ожидания 7 секунд

Comment: Варианты, которые я вижу: 1. случается `InterruptedException` 2. какой-то другой код меняет переменную. Добавьте лог с временем в `catch` блок и в точку присвоения `false`. И конечно убедитесь, что переменная `volatile` (это не может быть причиной этой проблемы, но из-за этого столкнетесь с другими при расследовании и далее в пользовании).

Comment: @RomanKonoval, как добавлять лог со временем, не знаю, поэтому добавил со строкой (хотя, учитывая то, что во время дебага, не было захода в блок catch ни разу, не думаю, что это принципиально) 
по поводу второй догадки, просмотрел весь код, переменная нигде меняться не должна. Более того, у меня есть место, с таким же кодом для другой переменной и там результат тот же.
С volatile всё в порядке

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так. В данном случае содержимое метода run() выполнится через 7 секунд :

```
    if(immortalityOn){
    Log.d("immortalityOn", String.valueOf(immortalityOn));
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             immortalityOn = false;
        }
    }, 7000);
 }
```

Comment: Почему не работает оригинальный код с Thread-ом?

Comment: С этим кодом тоже не получилось

Comment: Я попробовал объединить Ваш и мой варианты (добавил в текст вопроса), но получилось не особо хорошо

Comment: Вернулся к первоначальному варианту и сделал так, чтобы переменная, находящаяся в if, меняла значение по нажатию кнопки, результат: меняю переменную на false, она ждёт 7 секунд, меняет значение immortalityOn на false, но после, когда переменная immortalityOn получает значение true, оно сразу меняется на false, без ожидания 7 секунд

Comment: Протестил несколько раз этот код, переменная успешно меняет свое значение. Изменения отображал в логах. Возможно стоит посмотреть на ваш код целиком

Comment: она меняет значение, но не через 7 секунд, а сразу, то есть почему-то игнорируется сон потока

Answer (score 0):

Если объявить `immortalityOn` как `volatile` не работает?

```
volatile boolean immortalityOn=true;    
if(immortalityOn){
    Log.d("immortalityOn", String.valueOf(immortalityOn));
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(7000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            immortalityOn = false;
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: нет, не работает

Comment: Вернулся к первоначальному варианту и сделал так, чтобы переменная, находящаяся в if, меняла значение по нажатию кнопки, результат: меняю переменную на false, она ждёт 7 секунд, меняет значение immortalityOn на false, но после, когда переменная immortalityOn получает значение true, оно сразу меняется на false, без ожидания 7 секунд

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант - при нажатии кнопки четко через 7 секунд меняется значение.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private boolean immortalityOn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            immortalityOn = true;
            Log.d("MainActivity", "immortalityOn=" + immortalityOn);
            if (immortalityOn)
                setImmortality(false);
        });
    }

    private void setImmortality(boolean value) {
        Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(7000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            handler.post(() -> {
                immortalityOn = value;
                Log.d("MainActivity", "immortalityOn=" + immortalityOn);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: к сожалению, результат тот же